# cannot use useContext in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs

I am using Context API to escape prop drilling and I have created context like:

```
const {
  Provider,
  Consumer,
} = React.createContext<Context>({
  carNames: [],
});
```

and Providing the context like:

```
<Provider
      value={{
        carNames
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </Provider>
```

So, to consume the context value I wanted to use `useContext()` BUT since I destructured Consumer and Provider out of createContext. What value should I pass to the argument of `useContext(???)`. Tried this `useContext({Consumer, Provider})` but no result .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to deconstruct it. Here is an working example:

App.tsx

```
import { ContextProvider } from "../ContextProvider";

...

  const contextValue = {
    carValues,
    setCarValues,
  };

  return (
    <ContextProvider.Provider value={contextValue}>
      ...
    </ContextProvider.Provider>
  );
};
```

ContextProvider.tsx

```
export interface IContextProvider {
  carValues: ICarVlaues[];
  setCarValues: Dispatch<SetStateAction<ICarValues[]>>;
}

export const ContextProvider = createContext<IContextProvider>({
  carValues: [],
  setCarValues: () => {},
});
```

Use it like so:

```
  const { carValues } = useContext(ContextProvider);
```